# Generate not existing method like Visual Studio in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

In Visual Studio we can write a method name and then by clicking <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> Visual Studio will automatically generate the method with appropriate parameters, if any.

Say for example that you have this oversimplified Swift code in xcode:

```swift
struct Travel {
    var expectedTime: Double
}
```

For which you create an instance

```swift
var itenaryLondonToParis = Travel(expectedTime: 2.27)
```

and then you type a non-existing method call:

```swift
itenaryLondonToParis.getTime()
```

At this point xcode would, if the user asks for it with some keyboard command or similar, suggest the possibility of creating the method `getTime()` inside `Travel`:

```swift
func getTime(){
    //generated placeholder method
}
```

which the user later can edit to something more useful.

Is there something like that in Xcode?

Comment: Are you asking about something beyond Xcode's autocomplete?

Comment: I don't know what is it?

Comment: I wonder the same thing for xcode 14. So far I haven't found a way that allows you to, for example to type a method call for an instance, a method that does not  exist and get a suggestion to create this non-existing method. This instead of just getting a message there is no such member.
This type of moment often happens when you develop with TDD.

Comment: Xcode doesn't do this.